# The font of my dropdown button in the navbar is an other font then the other titles

Tags: html, css, navbar

So I made this navigation bar and there is 1 title which is a dropdown menu. This title has an other font then the others. If you hover over this dropdown menu, the links do have the right font. Can someone help me with this?

```css
/* Navbar */
    .topnav {
        list-style-type: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #363636;
        box-shadow: 0px 6px 13px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
        transition: all .2s ease-in;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 24px 26px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
        color: #bdbdbd;
    }

    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }

    /* Dropdown container */
    .dropdown {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      /* Dropdown button */
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size:16px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 24px 26px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif; 
        font-style: inherit;
        margin: 0; 
      }

    /* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }

      /* Links inside the dropdown */
      .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: black ;
        padding: 24px 26px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }

      /* Background dropdown links */
      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }

      /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
      }
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <div class="max-width">
        <section class="gray">
              <a href="#head">Home</a>
              <a href="#about">About</a>
              <a href="#gamemodes">Gamemodes</a>
              <a href="#vote">Vote</a>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Application </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#Staff">Staff</a>
                  <a href="#Staff">Donators</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a href="https://slamstore.buycraft.net">STORE</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
```

Navbar:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLEeO.png

Navbar with dropdown:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzEa7.png

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the rest of your nav links are `a` elements, but your rogue nav link is a `button` element.

If the drop-down button isn't meant to look different you could just remove the font styling from it:

```
      /* Dropdown button */
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        // font-size:16px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        // color: white;
        padding: 24px 26px;
        background-color: inherit;
        // font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif; 
        font-style: inherit;
        margin: 0; 
      }
```

And wrap an `a` element around the rogue nav link.